# Как в приложении Android сделать переключение тем?

Tags: java, android, themes, android-style

У меня порядка 7 активностей и где-то в 6й мне надо вставить в настройки переключатель выбора светлой или темной темы.

Использование данного кода не помогает:

```
public void theme(View view){       
    getApplication().setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Holo);
}
```

Читал, что надо прописывать отдельный класс, который вызывать в каждом классе активностей перед `setContentView`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Для смены темы "на лету" нужно проделать довольно нудные манипуляции.

Обычно же все это происходит в настройках.
Через метод `setTheme()` вы можете устанавливать нужную тему в каждом активити, изменения вступят в силу после перезапуска активити (возврата из настроек), в которой есть смена темы. Метод должен применяться ДО метода `setContentView()`.

Текущую выбранную тему лучше всего хранить в `SharedPreferences`, записывая туда значение из настроек, а при запуске активити считывать оттуда.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    int theme = sp.getInt("THEME", R.style.AppTheme);
    setTheme(theme); 

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
}
```

где значение ключа "THEME", которое будет записываться в настройках, равно ID выбранной темы, заданной в *res/styles.xml*, так, для примера со стилями ниже это будут значения: `R.style.AppTheme` и `R.style.AppThemeLight`

**UPD**

Для тем основанных на `AppCompat` темы применяются не полностью, чтобы решить эту проблему обязательно нужно указывать цвета `ColorPrimary`, `ColorPrimaryDark` и `ColorAccent` в файле `styles.xml`с темами, которые будут менятся в приложении:

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppThemeLight" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_light</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark_light</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent_light</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Определяем сами цвета (вы можете выбрать свои, какие нравятся) в **colors.xml**:

```
<resources>
    <color name="primary_light">#edeceb</color>
    <color name="accent_light">#517c50</color>
    <color name="primary_dark_light">#0d0c0c</color>
    <color name="primary">#2d2c2a</color>
    <color name="accent">#a5c0df</color>
    <color name="primary_dark">#e2e0e0</color>
</resources>
```

Для тем, основанных на `Holo` так же нужно указать некоторые параметры , чтобы не было проблем:

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>
 <style name="AppThemeLight" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:background">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/LightActionBar</item>
 </style>

 <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:background">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/BlackActionBar</item>
 </style>

 <style name="LightActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#FFFFFF</item>
 </style>

 <style name="BlackActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#000000</item>
 </style>
</resources>
```

PS: Гарантированное применение темы произойдет при перезапуске приложения (а вообще при перезапуске активити, что происходит не всегда, так как они не обязательно уничтожаются при переходах)

Comment: Активити пересоздавать не обязательно, достаточно пересоздать фрагмент[ы] из которых эта активити состоит... Ну, it depends, да...

Comment: Попробовал, темы переключает. Но все равно остается белый текст на белом фоне в светлой теме. Это может быть из-за использования Appcompat?

Comment: У меня тоже такоеже, использую смену тем, смену темы, например на черную, заголовок остается черным и так черный на черном не оч. А щяс попробовал как вы сказали, так ваще интересный баг выходит

Comment: Например вот так если сделать смену темы выше super.OnCreate выходит два статус бара!!! Тема применилась на второй статус бар) а само приложение белое)

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/HGUX6iDlibKN7

Comment: Такчто это функция очень не хорошая!

Comment: @ДенисКотляров На самом деле очень нехорошо не думать своей головой для решения проблемы, а списывать свои неумения на несчастные "нехорошие" функции. Обновил ответ. Вас это не очень может обрадует, но у меня почему то все работает и нет никаких двойных статусбаров и темы применяются куда им следует.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ, он мне помог решить проблему. А насчет не думать головой - не совсем так. Очень много перечитал и пересмотрел, иначе бы не стал спрашивать. Но спасибо. Теперь все работает нормально.

Answer (score 1):

В общем, сработало даже без определения основных цветов.

в стилях задаем три темы:

```
style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat"></style>
style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme"></style>
style  name="AppTheme.Light" parent = "Theme.AppCompat.Light"></style>
```

в манифесте:

```
   > android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"
```

в каждой активности (идет проверка переменной, содержащей значение темы):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (MainActivity.theme.equals("white")) {
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Light);
        } else setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

и непосредственно переключатель (перегружает активность и ставит переменную в нужный цвет для остальных):

```
MainActivity.theme="white";
Intent intent2 = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(intent2);
```

Comment: Не рекомендуется использовать поле активити для хранения значений вне этой активити, так как оно в любое время может быть утрачено. Используйте `SharedPreferences` для хранения выбранной темы.

Comment: Вы правы, но SharedPreferences не работают почему-то у меня, как ни пляшу с бубном. Понятно, что выбранная тема не сохранится после перезапуска приложения у меня, но сохранить их в файл пока не получается(

Comment: Создайте вопрос со своей проблемой, возможно вам помогут его решить. Тема не только не сохранится при перезапуске, но может быть довольно легко потеряна и во время работы приложения.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, попробую! Это пока временная заглушка, пока не заработает полноценное сохранение.

Answer (score 0):

Нам достаточно всего двух методов для включения темной или светлой темы:

**AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);** //Первая функция включает темную тему
**AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);** //Вторая функция включает светлую тему

Вы можете реализовать SharedPreferences для сохранения результата

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]