# Смена темы в Android приложении (UPD)

Tags: java, android, android-style, android-themes

Есть две темы: светлая (AppTheme) и темная (DarkTheme).

styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<style name="DarkTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat" >
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accentDark</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryVeryDark</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryDark</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

UPD. Хотелось бы реализовать быструю смену тем, "на лету". Т.е. не заходя в настройки, по нажатию кнопки темы менялись бы со светлой на темную и наоборот. Подобное есть в приложении Pocket.(Да, там нужно заходить в настройки, но тема меняется сразу же после нажатия на соответствующий пункт меню). Как такое реализовать?

Comment: тема таким образом не поменяется. Нужно как минимум пересоздать `Activity`

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте перегрузить метод активити

```
onApplyThemeResource(Resources.Theme theme, int resid, boolean first) {
    theme.applyStyle(resid, true);
}
```

Данный метод вызывается после `setTheme()`

Answer (score 0):

Тему для активити надо проставлять в `onCreate` **до** строчки `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

Так что, вам надо вместо применения темы к активити, кою вы сразу пересоздаёте, записать нужную новую тему куда-нить (в настройки, они же `SharedPreferences`) и эту тему устанавливать в `onCreate` **до** строчки `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`.

Подробнее тут: [Как в приложении Android сделать переключение тем?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/440430/17609)

Answer (score 0):

Создайте Экран настроек и добавьте там  ListView с выбором темы. Затем в методе onCreate берите String и через if-else меняйте тему.