# Как изменять тему при определённом месяце в Android приложении?

Tags: java, android, android-style, android-themes

Всем здравствуйте! Хочу реализовать изменение оформления при определённом месяце. Читал много других вопросов на форуме - мне не помогло, оформление не изменяется. Theme Editor показывает, что должны все компоненты изменяться, но изменяется только цвет мигающего курсора в EditText, всё остальное остаётся по-прежнему. Надо изменить всё то, на что указано стрелочкой.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код для изменения темы:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    int january = sp.getInt("JANUARY", R.style.January);
    int february = sp.getInt("FEBRUARY", R.style.February);
    int march = sp.getInt("MARCH", R.style.March);
    int april = sp.getInt("APRIL", R.style.April);
    int may = sp.getInt("MAY", R.style.May);
    int june = sp.getInt("JUNE", R.style.June);
    int jule = sp.getInt("JULE", R.style.Jule);
    int august = sp.getInt("AUGUST", R.style.August);
    int september = sp.getInt("SEPTEMBER", R.style.September);
    int october = sp.getInt("OCTOBER", R.style.October);
    int november = sp.getInt("NOVEMBER", R.style.November);
    int december = sp.getInt("DECEMBER", R.style.December);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText);
    mainSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.MainSpinner);
    newSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.NewSpinner);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button);
    newPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NewPassword);
    password = "12345";
    final DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    width = metrics.widthPixels;
    Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
    Month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);

    switch (Month) {
        case 0: {setTheme(january);}
        break;
        case 1: {setTheme(february);}
        break;
        case 2: {setTheme(march);}
        break;
        case 3: {setTheme(april);}
        break;
        case 4: {setTheme(may);}
        break;
        case 5: {setTheme(june);}
        break;
        case 6: {setTheme(jule);}
        break;
        case 7: {setTheme(august);}
        break;
        case 8: {setTheme(september);}
        break;
        case 9: {setTheme(october);}
        break;
        case 10: {setTheme(november);}
        break;
        case 11: {setTheme(december);}
        break;
    }

}
```

styles.xml:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="January" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/JanuaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/JanuaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/JanuaryColor</item>
</style>

<style name="February" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/FebruaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/FebruaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/FebruaryColor</item>
</style>

<style name="March" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/MarchColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/MarchColor</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/MarchColor</item>
</style>

<style name="April" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/AprilColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/AprilColor</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/AprilColor</item>
</style>

<style name="May" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/MayColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/MayColor</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/MayColor</item>
</style>

<style name="June" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/JuneColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/JuneColor</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/JuneColor</item>
</style>

<style name="Jule" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/JuleColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/JuleColor</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/JuleColor</item>
</style>

<style name="August" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/AugustColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/AugustColor</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/AugustColor</item>
</style>

<style name="September" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/SeptemberColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/SeptemberColor</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/SeptemberColor</item>
</style>

<style name="October" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/OctoberColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/OctoberColor</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/OctoberColor</item>
</style>

<style name="November" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/NovemberColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/NovemberColor</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/NovemberColor</item>
</style>

<style name="December" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/DecemberColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/DecemberColor</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/DecemberColor</item>
</style>
```

colors.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
<color name="ChangeColor">#bdff62</color>
<color name="DefaultColor">#8a8a8a</color>
<color name="JanuaryColor">#ff00aeff</color>
<color name="FebruaryColor">#00fff7</color>
<color name="MarchColor">#00ffc8</color>
<color name="AprilColor">#00ffa1</color>
<color name="MayColor">#00ff08</color>
<color name="JuneColor">#d9ff00</color>
<color name="JuleColor">#ffff00</color>
<color name="AugustColor">#ffd000</color>
<color name="SeptemberColor">#ffae00</color>
<color name="OctoberColor">#ff7b00</color>
<color name="NovemberColor">#ff0400</color>
<color name="DecemberColor">#0400ff</color>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.testprogram.alex.program20000.MainActivity"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:clickable="true">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/LoadButtonText"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="81dp"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:onClick="onClick"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/EditText"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button"
    android:layout_marginBottom="38dp"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button"
    android:inputType="text" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/MainSpinner"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/EditText"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/EditText"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/EditText"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/EditText"
    android:popupBackground="#b60000" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/NewSpinner"
    android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/EditText"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/EditText"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/EditText"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/EditText"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/EditText"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:popupBackground="#a6ff9e" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/NewPassword"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:password="true"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:hint="@string/oldpassword_hint" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_test_arena.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.testprogram.alex.program20000.TestArena">

<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    android:progress="0"
    android:layout_marginBottom="202dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/loop"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_above="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/seekBar"
    android:checked="false" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/unknown_position"
    android:id="@+id/CurrentPos"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
    android:textColor="#8a8a8a" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/unknown_position"
    android:id="@+id/MaxPos"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/CurrentPos"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/seekBar"
    android:textColor="#8a8a8a" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:contentDescription="@string/play_pause_button"
    android:src="@drawable/pause_standard"
    android:layout_above="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkBox"
    android:onClick="play_pause_click" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:contentDescription="@string/stop_button"
    android:src="@drawable/stop_standard"
    android:layout_marginRight="38dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="38dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView2"
    android:onClick="stop_click" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Пожалуйста, помогите мне разобраться с проблемой!

Comment: У Вас 11 не используемых переменных - january, february etc. По хорошему их нужно инициализировать внутри switch.

Comment: метод `setTheme()` должен вызываться [ДО вызова метода `setContentView()`](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/440441/177345)

Comment: @pavlofff Я сразу то и не заметил это. Спасибо за помощь! Работает!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поставил этот код до **setContentView**:

```
Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
    Month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);

    switch (Month) {
        case 0: {setTheme(january);}
        break;
        case 1: {setTheme(february);}
        break;
        case 2: {setTheme(march);}
        break;
        case 3: {setTheme(april);}
        break;
        case 4: {setTheme(may);}
        break;
        case 5: {setTheme(june);}
        break;
        case 6: {setTheme(jule);}
        break;
        case 7: {setTheme(august);}
        break;
        case 8: {setTheme(september);}
        break;
        case 9: {setTheme(october);}
        break;
        case 10: {setTheme(november);}
        break;
        case 11: {setTheme(december);}
        break;
    }
```

И теперь всё отлично работает! Спасибо пользователю **@pavlofff**! Вопрос закрыт.