# Как программно(при нажатии кнопки) изменить бекграунд на всех экранах(Активити) приложения?

Tags: android, background, color

Я сделал код, который при нажатии кнопки меняет фон, но работает он только для той активити, на которой находится эта кнопка. Могу ли я как-то с помощью это кнопки изменить фон абсолютно на всех экранах приложения?

```
 RelativeLayout view = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlid);
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background2);
```

Как с одного Активити достучаться до остальных? У меня есть 2 радиобаттона(темный фон и светлый). Мне нужно если пользователь на Start_activity выбрал радиобаттон2(светлый) чтоб на всех остальных фон так же стал светлым

Comment: Нужно нажатии на кнопку сохранить в преференсы (или куда удобнее) вариант фона и в каждой активности при старте проверять какой вариант сохранён и ставить соответствующий фон.

Comment: можно [создать две темы и переключать их программно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/440441/177345), но это больше подходит для более существенных визуальных изменений, чем только фон