# Как изменить фон TextView элемента в списке?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть класс `Main3Activity`, в нем я использую adapter

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.pro_item, titleList);
```

У меня также есть `R.layout.list_item`, а в нем `TextView` id у него "pro_item"
Как из класса `Main3Activity` изменить background `TextView`
по id?

Comment: У вас `TextView` с `id` `"pro_item"` будет в каждом элементе списка, который виден на экране. Вы хотите покрасить все элементы списка? - тогда установите фон прямо в макете или создайте свой класс адаптера и ставьте фон в нём. Опишите хотелку подробнее - в чём великий замысел?

Comment: Я хочу  сделать чёрную тему и проблема возникает в том что по умолчанию у меня стоит цвет фона белый в HTML
Я хочу как-то установить  его на чёрный но не знаю как это сделать программно.Как это сделать с помощью класса?

Answer (score 1):

Поменять из активити фон TextView, являющегося часть макета элемента списка, не получится.

1. Если эти фоны должны быть одинаковы во всех элементах Вашего списка - поменяйте фон в макете и все.
2. Если у разных элементов списка эти TextView-хи должны иметь разный фон - передавайте эти фоны массивом (или ArrayList-ом или еще чем-нибудь) в адаптер (как параметр конструктора) и используйте при прорисовке итема листа. Или передавайте условие, определяющее фон и в зависимости от него опять же ставьте нужный фон при прорисовке.
3. Если же менять фон нужно у уже готового списка, то см. п. 2 плюс перерисовка нужного итема (у которого меняется фон TextView) - `notifyDataSetChanged()` для ListView и/или `notifyItemInserted(int position)`, `notifyItemRemoved(int position)`, `notifyItemChanged(int position)` для RecyclerView

Comment: Вы правы все элементы у меня одинаковые  и устанавливаются через HTML в белый цвет.Проблема в чём что я хочу сделать чёрную тему , Как установить черный цвет программно. Из другого класса у layout нет своего класса .

Comment: Т..е Вы хотите "на лету" по какому-то событию изменить этот цвет? Тогда предавайте в адаптер некий флаг, обозначающий темный нужно рисовать цвет или светлый. При наступлении нужного события отдавайте адаптеру измененное значение флага и опять-таки notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Я хотел сделать это таким образом .Перед тем как будет работать адаптер    через r.id подключиться и изменить программно  TextView элемента списка"pro_item" . Как-то так     View someView = findViewById(R.id.pro_item);
        View root = someView.getRootView();
        root.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.background_light)); но сделать это нужно из другого класса.

Comment: @Дмитрий, не всё так просто - вы сделаете фон тёмным и текст сольётся с фоном, в общем придётся менять цвета и текста, и разделителей, и чего-то ещё. Может вам подойдёт выбор темы всей активности при старте из заготовленных заранее стилей: [Как в приложении Android сделать переключение тем?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/440430/11515)

Comment: Да я согласен, что нужно будет  много поменять меня это не пугает просто как зацепить элемент по r.id   .Код что я подставил вверху вылетает программа с ним падает