# Как поменять тему в приложений с помощью переключателя (Switch)

Tags: java, android

Как при переключений режимов переключателя менялась тема?

Comment: Как бы свитч это просто триггер, который меняет состояние вкл/выкл и все. Сам по себе он не меняет никакие темы, и тут мы приходим к пониманию, что для корректного вопроса нужно определиться: вы умеете менять темы в принципе, но не знаете как это реализовать через свитч или вы не знаете, как вообще поменять тему, но думаете, что свитч в этом поможет?

Comment: я не понимаю ни как поменять тему, ни как работает свитч. Посмотрел кучу видосов как поменять тему, но везде старая версия Android Studio где присутствует style.xml, так что я думал мне тут кто-то поможет)

Comment: В общем то от версии студии способы изменения темы в андроид не меняются никак, так же, если вы хотите достигнуть каких то реальных результатов в программировании, то стоит прекращать смотреть "видосы" и начинать читать профильную литературу по программированию, учебники. По смене темы есть тут уже вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/440441/177345 . В общем то ничего не изменилось. Смотря "видосы", своей программы вы никогда не напишите, даже если вам тут полностью готовый код напишут

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. При смене положения переключателя сохраняйте куда-то (в префы, например) условный ID темы/стиля.
2. Устанавливайте тему в активити до `super.onCreate(bundle)` согласно сохранённому в п.1 значению.
3. При смене положения переключателя пересоздавайте активити. (метод `recreate()`, вроде бы)